# how do you use your class from the windows form in C++?

Tags: winforms

The way I do it does compile and gives a working code, but the visual designer issues an error.

Should I just give up on the visual designer, and continue typing the code manually?

Details: I created a class using Visual Studio 2017. in C++. 
I added my class using right click in Solution Explorer. 
I created one method. 
I tried to follow the same way of initializing, by doing this: MyClass^ myClass = (gcnew MyClass()); However, design view gave me the following error: "Coud not find type 'MyClass'. Please mak sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced...." I searched far and wide for the solution of this in other forums, only to get about two million questions and answers ( I am not kidding). I read first 20 or 30, and all the answers are different.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on my question. The right way to use my own class while working with the Microsoft Form Designer, is to instantiate the class within the Form1() public constructor. This shall not be done within the InitializeComponent() method, since that obviously (after a bit of debugging), interferes with the Visual Designer.